# attributes in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the facebook Graph API. the actual message of the object appears as "message": or "story":

Example:

```
{
     "id": "148550335191249_236850319694583",
     "from": {
        "name": "Sinners Highway",
        "category": "Musician/band",
        "id": "148550335191249"
     },
     "story": "Sinners Highway edited their Biography and Band Interests.",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": 148550335191249,
              "name": "Sinners Highway",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 15
           }
        ]
     },
     "type": "status",
     "created_time": "2011-09-02T21:49:50+0000",
     "updated_time": "2011-09-02T21:49:50+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
```

and this one:

```
{
     "id": "148550335191249_258570210855927",
     "from": {
        "name": "Sinners Highway",
        "category": "Musician/band",
        "id": "148550335191249"
     },
     "message": "LETS GET ROCKIN'! ",
     "picture": "http://platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php?app=123966167614127&v=1&size=z&cksum=81c39517d99ba86af6a77df2c4879810&src=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fstatic.bandsintown.com\u00252Fimages\u00252Ffacebook\u00252Fpromote\u00252Fnew-date.png",
     "link": "http://bnds.in/q0cSbN",
     "name": "Sinners Highway \u0040 The Grange in Nottingham, United Kingdom",
     "caption": "Sunday, November 27, 2011 at 6:00pm",
     "properties": [
        {
           "name": "Tickets",
           "text": "http://bnds.in/nqft0W",
           "href": "http://bnds.in/nqft0W"
        },
        {
           "name": "More Tour Dates",
           "text": "http://bnds.in/oZ6VTg",
           "href": "http://bnds.in/oZ6VTg"
        }
     ],
     "type": "link",
     "application": {
        "name": "Bandsintown",
        "canvas_name": "concertsbybit",
        "namespace": "concertsbybit",
        "id": "123966167614127"
     },
     "created_time": "2011-10-21T17:44:12+0000",
     "updated_time": "2011-10-21T20:01:31+0000",

  },
```

From what I can tell its completely random whether it is a message or a story.

Does anybody know where and when the story attribute is used and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from those two examples, the noticeable difference is that the story was an activity that was auto-posted about something the band did on facebook (editing their profile), whereas the message was something that someone has posted on the page wall.